# Can't insert values into table, foreign key constraint keeps failing

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1452

I'm trying to insert this code into my Albums table on my MySQL database

```
INSERT INTO `Albums` (`Albumid`, `Name`, `Numberoftracks`, `Artistid`,     ]
`Genre`) VALUES (1, "Innuendo", 12, "Queen", "Rock");
```

But every time I try to I keep getting this error.

```
1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`b4014107_db1/Albums`, CONSTRAINT `Albums_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Artistid`) 
REFERENCES `Artist` (`Artistid`))
```

I know it's something to do with my foreign key within the table, but I need to manually enter the foreign key because it's not auto-incremented.

Here's the tables code.

```
CREATE TABLE `Albums` (  `Albumid` int(6) NOT NULL,  `Name` varchar(50) NOT 
NULL,  `Numberoftracks` int(11) NOT NULL,  `Artistid` int(6) NOT NULL,  
`Genre` varchar(50) NOT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY  (`Albumid`),  KEY `Artistid` 
(`Artistid`),  CONSTRAINT `Albums_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Artistid`)   
REFERENCES `Artist` (`Artistid`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

How do I fix this? I need to input data into the table.

Comment: Have you added the artist "Queen" on the artist table? Because if not, you should add the artist first otherwise your FK will always be violated.

Comment: Also, ArtistId is a number and you are trying to add a VARCHAR there. You should add the artist 'Queen' on table artist and get the ArtistId to use in this insert of yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`artistid` is a foreign key in the table `Albums`. Parent child relationship error comes when you try to insert a foreign key in child table which is not present in the parent table. `artistid` is not present in your `Artist` table.

Also, to add the the datatype of `artistid` is also different.

Taken from [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

> Foreign key relationships involve a parent table that holds the
>   central data values, and a child table with identical values pointing
>   back to its parent. The FOREIGN KEY clause is specified in the child
>   table.
>
> It will reject any INSERT or UPDATE operation that attempts to create
>   a foreign key value in a child table if there is no a matching
>   candidate key value in the parent table.

To remove your error, insert the `Queens` artist in your `Artist` table first and then you can insert it into `Albums` table. Also correct the datatype of column `artistid`.

Answer (score 0):

Using foreign keys doesn't mean any implicit auto-incrementation. A foreign key in a table means that a record must already exist in another.
see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html (change version in the url regarding your needs)

Otherwise, make a trigger if you want the artist to be dynamically created.

Hope it'll clarify.